# Data In Input Box Not Going to JavaScript var

Tags: javascript, php

Good day! I want to write an ajax request passing two variables to the controller. The problem is that I cannot get the values from the textboxes to my JavaScript

This is the JavaScript and the HTML code.

When I alert the day variable I get nothing it shows that the field is empty. I am very new to programming

```
    $('#historic_form').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
            var fund_id = $(this).val();
            var day = $(this).val();
    
            //data = $('#historic_form').serialize();
    
            $.ajax({
    
                url:'Search/Searchday',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                data: {fund_id: fund_id, day: day},
                error: function() {
                    alert(day);},
                success: function(response) {
                    $("tbody").append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+description+"</td></tr>");
                }
            });
        });
```

And below are my HTML Codes

```
<select required id="member_id" name="member_id" class="form-control">
        <option selected disabled>Select Member</option>
         <?php for ($i=0;$i<$fMembers->num_rows();$i++){
            echo "<option value='".$fMembers->row($i)->id."'>".$fMembers->row($i)->member_name."</option>";}?>
    </select>
        
    <select required class="form-control" id="fund_id" name="fund_id">
     <option selected disabled>Select Fund</option>
    </select>
    <input type="date" required name="day" placeholder="Select a date" class="form-control datepicker hasDatepicker" data-dateformat="dd/mm/yy" id="histDate">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $('#historic_form').submit(function(e) {
> ```

Your event handler is triggered by a form submission, so inside the function `this` will refer to the `<form>`.

> ```
> var fund_id = $(this).val();
> var day = $(this).val();
> ```

`<form>` elements don't have values. You need to [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the `<select>` element you want to read the value from and call `val()` on *that*.

Comment: ```var fund_id = find('#fund_id').val();
var day = find('#day').val();```   I tried this but still didn't get anything.

Comment: @DavidHangula — `find` is a method on jQuery objects, not a global.